# How can I fix the footer to dynamically change with height of the grid sections as they increase?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm trying to make this page footer go to the bottom always. But see the image and look whats happening.

How can I fix that? I know the yellow thing is weird but that's where actually the links would go when the website is done. so consider this like "testing".

I just want the footer to stop becoming "less" than the body contents (divs)
I want it to always be at the bottom

Here is image: [click here for image. Edit doc is the footer section basically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxztZ.jpg)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title></title>
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="images/logo.ico">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <link href="css/homepageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/viewDocsStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <a href=""><img class="logoImage" border="0" alt="logo" src="images/logo.gif"></a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="ContentSection1" id="blueStretched">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2" id="left">
                Team Created Docs
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="center">
                Doc View
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" id="right">
                Team Chat
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="location.href='';">Edit Document</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#left {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 7.75%;
    padding-bottom: 60%;
}
#center {
    background-color: Lightblue;
    left: 8%;
    text-align: center;
}
#right {
    background-color: gray;
    left: 8.25%;
}

footer{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#blueStretched{
    background-color: AliceBlue ;
    height: 75%;
}

header {
    padding: 20px 0;
    background: url(../images/HPbg.jpg) no-repeat 100% 0%; 
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    padding: 25px 0;
    background-color: #99CCCC;
    text-align: center;
}

.logoImage { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 47%;
    top: 3.5%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.ContentSection1 {
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-color: AliceBlue ;
}

body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Do you always want it to be at the bottom of the user's view, or at the bottom of the page below the content?

Comment: @BurningLights well it doesnt matter, as long as its in the bottom lol. like no matter how much the content extends dynamically, the footer should extend with it dynamically so that it i s always at the bottom of all the page content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set up your footer and main content like this:

```
#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -20%;
    height: -20%;
    clear:both;} 

#blueStretched {
    background-color: AliceBlue;
    overflow:hidden;
      padding-bottom: 0%;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajoLgL4o/24/

Comment: awesome. this works. thanks! altho, how come without calling #footer in the html file the effect from the CSS file is somehow applied? like i had to use id="bluestretched" for blue stretched stuff to apply to the page, but i didnt have to call id="footer" in the html page yet the effect applied somehow? is it because footer is a keyword so it connects it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. I believe it is because of a `margin` overlap. Try giving `overflow: hidden` to the `footer`:

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check out using the fiddle, it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: i did see the fiddle. however, if you scroll a little to the right, you will see that something is not right with the overlay of the footer and the contentsection

Comment: Ah, is it so? Did you use a reset?

Comment: um thats not helpful to my case lol. i dont think the browser is the one changing or applying their own CSS sheets to that complexity.

Comment: @goldensunplayer If you had clicked on the link, you would have known.

Comment: o right sry about that. lol i am sleepy now so i wasnt focused.

altho, i have multiple CSS files of bootstrap and what not...its gonna be a mess tryna upload all those

Answer (score 0):

Create a new css stylesheet then insert the code below.

```
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin-top:50px;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Then insert your new stylesheet/custom below the bootstrap css. Then create a div and put an id of "footer".

```
<div class="footer">
  Footer here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
footer{padding:1rem;}
#blueStretched{background-color: AliceBlue ;}
```

You have to edit your footer and remove everything except the padding.
And you have to remove the height of your #blueStretched

Comment: close solution, but the footer thins out (which isnt a big deal in my case) but there will be a small space difference between the div and footer. like when i editted your code in my CSS, the yello stretched all the way as it should, then there was some indentation just showing the alice blue, then the footer.

Answer (score 0):

A small change in your code. Try this...

```
footer{
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: close solution, but the footer thins out (which isnt a big deal in my case) but there will be a small space difference between the div and footer. like when i editted your code in my CSS, the yello stretched all the way as it should, then there was some indentation just showing the alice blue, then the footer

Comment: provide a fiddle and we track it down